# order a list by the `snd` of a tuple within that list:

Tags: list, haskell

I have the following list of tuples:

```
[("a",6),("b",1),("c",2),("d",4),("e",1),("f",1),("g",5),("h",3),("i",1),("j",2)]
```

but would like to `order` the tuples in the list by the `snd` element of the tuple. That way, I get an answer similar to:

```
[("b",1),("e",1),("f",1),("i",1),("c",2),("j",2),("h",3),("d",4),("g",5),("a",6)]
```

(i.e. the list is ordered by the second (`snd`) of each tuple.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
sortBy (comparing snd)
```

where `sortBy` is in `List` and `comparing` is in `Data.Ord`.

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative to jleedev's answer:

```
sortBy (compare `on` snd)
```

where `sortBy` is in `Data.List` and `on` is in `Data.Function`.

IMO this formulation is slightly nicer because `compare` is just the standard class method from `Ord`, and `on` is a more generally useful function that `comparing`. But there's not much in it.

Answer (score 1):

Since Data.List 4.8.0.0 one can also use [`sortOn`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html) as follows: `sortOn snd`.