# Haskell - Remove n smallest elements in a list of tuples

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I've got the following code that takes  an int value and removes the first n amount of elements in a list.

```
removeEle :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
removeEle n xs
    | ((n <= 0) || null xs) = xs
    | otherwise = removeEle (n-1) (tail xs)
```

How would i append this so that this works on a list of tuples by their second element? etc

```
[(String1, 50)], [(String2, 600)], [(String3, 10)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not much you can do to amend your current solution so that it removes the first `n` smallest elements. To be able to remove the first `n` smallest, you need to have the total ordering of the whole list so that you can decide which elements are in the `n` smallest interval.

One easy solution is to sort the list and the remove the first `n` elements. This solution doesn't preserve the original ordering though.

Using [`soryBy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortBy) and [`drop`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:drop) from `Data.List` you can do the following:

```hs
removeNSmallest :: Ord a => Int -> [(String, a)] -> [(String, a)]
removeNSmallest n xs = drop n $ sortBy (\(_, a) (_, b) -> compare a b) xs
```

As @Micha Wiedenmann pointed out, you can use [sortBy (comparing snd)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170592/order-a-list-by-the-snd-of-a-tuple-within-that-list/6170614#6170614) for sorting the tuples.

A small test:

```
λ> removeNSmallest 1 [("String1", 50), ("String2", 600), ("String3", 10)]
[("String1",50),("String2",600)]
```

To preserve the original ordering, one solution is to create a separate ordered list of the second elements of the tuple. Then traverse the original list and for each element that is in the ordered list, remove one from the original.

Your original solution for removing the first n elements of a list would be much more readable if you wrote it using `drop`:

```hs
removeEle :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
removeEle n xs = drop n xs
```

Or if you want to use explicit recursion:

```hs
removeEle :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
removeEle _ [] = []
removeEle 0 xs = xs
removeEle n x:xs = removeEle (n-1) xs
```

Comment: Why are you sorting? And if you are sorting, how about [`sortBy (comparing snd)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6170614).

Comment: His code also handles `removeEle (-1) [1..]` differently from your version.

Comment: I didn't think their `removeEle` implementation was very clean and idiomatic, so I changed it. Regarding the sorting: Some type of sorting is required for removing the nth smallest elements or we would become very inefficient. I agree that this changes the ordering of the original list though which can be unacceptable based on requirements. For that case, I added how we can amend this solution for that case while still sorting. @MichaWiedenmann

Comment: Thanks. I see now that the title says "smallest" but the first sentence and the example do not.

Comment: Sure :D I also was confused by that at first.

Comment: Thanks, i actually needed the recursive version. I cant test right now but does removeEle work on the example [("String1", 50), ("String2", 600), ("String3", 10)]?

Comment: Yes, it works, provided you sort the list first to make sure you remove the smallest elements.